# Android listview delete data but listview not update

Tags: android, android-studio, listview

I delete data in SQLi but listview not update. I have to open activity agian then listview will update.

This is function delete data.

```
private void delData(int position) {


    cursor.moveToPosition(position);
    String rowId = cursor.getString(0);
    db.delete(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME, "_id = ?", new String[]{rowId});

    cursor.requery();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

This is function OnItemClick in OnCreate.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_driver);

    dbHelper = new DBHelper(DriverActivity.this);

    lv_driver=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv_driver);
    lv_driver.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            delData(i);

        }
    });
}
```

How to update listview after delete data ?

Comment: You have to remove data even from your list's datasouece.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I delete data in SQLi but `ListView` not update. I have to open activity again then `ListView` will update.

Yes, it's normal you are deleting the item from SQLite not from your `ListView`.

> How to update `ListView` after delete data ?

You can recreate the `ListView` or just remove your item `adapter.remove(position);`

Example :

```
private void delData(int position) {
    cursor.moveToPosition(position);
    String rowId = cursor.getString(0);
    db.delete(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME, "_id = ?", new String[]{rowId});   
    cursor.requery();
    adapter.remove(position);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have to remove in  List<Map<String,String>> lst .